# Were The Original Star Trek Sound Effects Used Before Star Trek?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos, sound-effects

So I'm watching through the old Twilight Zone and was watching an episode called "Third From The Sun". Towards the end, there's a scene where they use the Star Trek bridge sounds. I was under the impression that the sound effects were original to Star Trek and some research I've done has linked them to when the series was created and not before.

Is it possible the sound effects were apart of a sound library networks used? If so, who created the sound effects and how did they end up in that library?

Comment: This is addressed in the dupe. "*Virtually all the effects were new"* = Some of the effects were not new.